# htaccess IP blocking with custom 403 Error not working

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I'm trying to block everyone but 1 IP address from my site on a server running apache & centos. My setup is follows the example below.

**My server:**

```
`http://www.myserver.com/`
```

**My .htaccess file**

```
<limit GET> 
order deny,allow  
deny from all  
allow from 176.219.192.141
</limit>

ErrorDocument 403 http://www.google.com
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.google.com
```

When I visit `http://www.myserver.com/` from an invalid IP, it gives me a generic 403 error. When I visit `http://www.myserver.com/page-does-not-exist/` it redirects me correctly to `http://www.google.com` but I can't figure out why the 403 error doesn't redirect me too. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In some conditions, Apache doesn't like full URLs in `ErrorDocument`

Try redirecting to a local page that will redirect to google, and allow access to that page explicitly with:

```
ErrorDocument 403 google.html

<Files google.html>
 Order Allow, Deny
 Allow from all
</Files>
```